# How to get the information that google provides after authorization oautch 2 spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I did authorization through google in spring boot, but I can't figure out where spring throws the information that it should receive from the user after I logged in through google?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your implementation but you can get it from `SecurityContextHolder` like this ;

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```